# BalloonTip on some region of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I want to show the [balloon tip](https://balloontip.java.net/) on a specific region on a `JPanel`. I know how to do it on a `JComponent`.

I have a line on the `JPanel`, is it possible to show `BallonTip` only when the mouseover on the line.

Thanks

Comment: If you're referencing a class that isn't in the Java API, perhaps you should reference the [library](https://balloontip.java.net/) to avoid confusion.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, `JPanel` extends from `JComponent`, so basically, it's the same process.

[image: Balloon]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import net.java.balloontip.CustomBalloonTip;
import net.java.balloontip.examples.complete.Utils;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private CustomBalloonTip customBalloonTip;

        private Rectangle square = new Rectangle(50, 50, 200, 200);

        public TestPane() {
            customBalloonTip = new CustomBalloonTip(this,
                    new JLabel("<html>I'm a " + Utils.monospace("CustomBalloonTip") + ".</html>"),
                    square,
                    Utils.createBalloonTipStyle(),
                    Utils.createBalloonTipPositioner(),
                    null);
            customBalloonTip.setVisible(false);

            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (square.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                        customBalloonTip.setVisible(true);
                    } else {
                        customBalloonTip.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }

            });

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fill(square);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

**Now with point/line intersection**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import net.java.balloontip.CustomBalloonTip;
import net.java.balloontip.examples.complete.Utils;

public class TestBalloon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestBalloon();
    }

    public TestBalloon() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private CustomBalloonTip customBalloonTip;

        private List<Line2D> lines = new ArrayList<>(25);
        private Point2D hitPoint = null;

        public TestPane() {

            customBalloonTip = new CustomBalloonTip(this,
                    new JLabel("<html>I'm a " + Utils.monospace("CustomBalloonTip") + ".</html>"),
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1),
                    Utils.createBalloonTipStyle(),
                    Utils.createBalloonTipPositioner(),
                    null);
            customBalloonTip.setVisible(false);

            lines.add(new Line2D.Float(0, 0, 300, 300));
            lines.add(new Line2D.Float(300, 0, 0, 300));

            hitPoint = null;

            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

                    Point mp = e.getPoint();
                    Rectangle offset = null;

                    for (Line2D line : lines) {
                        double distance = line.ptSegDist(mp);
                        if (distance <= 4) {
                            offset = new Rectangle(mp, new Dimension(1, 1));
                        }
                    }

                    if (offset != null) {
                        System.out.println(offset);
                        customBalloonTip.setOffset(offset);
                        customBalloonTip.setVisible(true);
                    } else {
                        customBalloonTip.setVisible(false);
                    }

                    repaint();
                }

            });

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            for (Line2D line : lines) {
                g2d.draw(line);
            }

            if (hitPoint != null) {
                Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(hitPoint.getX() - 5, hitPoint.getY() + 5, 10, 10);
                g2d.fill(ellipse);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is referring to tooltips.

Comment: @JoshM You may be right, but I took the fact that they said *"I know how to do it on a JComponent"* they were actually talking about a tool tip...

Comment: @JoshM Ooo, that's pretty cool, might need to grab a copy myself ;) - Hopefully, the OP can expand on what they mean and can get some clarity

Comment: I want to do it with balloontip. not the JPanel's default tooltip.

Comment: @user2573071 Put that in you question and Ill see if I have time to check in on it...

Comment: Yes. CustomBalloonTip works on rectangle. But I want to show it on the line.

Comment: @user2573071 So, reduce the rectangle to a single line...height = 1?

Comment: nice. but that will work only if the line is either vertical or horizontal. I have lines in other angles also.

Comment: @user2573071 So long as you can calculate the line intersection with the mouse, it should be doable...

Comment: @user2573071 Remember, you can change the offset of the balloon dynamically as well

Comment: public Line2D getClickedLine(int x, int y) {
        int boxX = x - HIT_BOX_SIZE / 2;
        int boxY = y - HIT_BOX_SIZE / 2;

        int width = HIT_BOX_SIZE;
        int height = HIT_BOX_SIZE;

        //for (Line2D line : getLines()) {
        if (line.intersects(boxX, boxY, width, height)) {
            return line;
        }
        // }
        return null;

    }

Comment: I can get it by the above code. but how can i determine when to show and when not to show?

Comment: Basically if that method returns a non `null` value within the `mouseMoved` event, then you should show it...

Comment: Looks like we need to write a new class same line CustomBalloonTip to work on the lines. I still cannot find a way to do with the existing classes.